# Dumping the contents of HTTP packets between two VPNs

Tags: vpn, iptables, http, socat

Here's my setup:

> Client ---> VPN 1 (my pc, same subnet of the client) --> VPN 2 (external VPN) --> Internet

Both VPNs are L2TP/IPSec and the first one is an Ubuntu server with Openswan.

I need to record the HTTP requests and responses of each client, so I need to be able to read them before they're encrypted and sent to the second VPN.

So, since the first VPN is on my PC, I thought that I could be able to log the packets here.

But how can I do it?

Is there any way to get them after they're decrypted by the first VPN and before they're encrypted to be sent to the second one?

Comment: Just log?  Or do you need to dump the contents of each packet as well?

Comment: I need to dump them as well

Comment: Question amended accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [tshark](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) and the [related tools](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/) to capture the packets on the interface between your PC and the client and analyze them.

You may get some milage out of [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) too, which is an HTTP proxy / HTTP monitor / Reverse Proxy that enables a developer to view all of the HTTP ...

Answer (score 1):

While @iain's answer is perfectly correct, assuming your client is a windows system I would suggest you use [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) for this instead. tcpdump/tshark/wireshark is a great tool for general network sniffing but fiddler is specifically designed for debugging http(s).

Comment: Clients are both Windows and Linux (generally Ubuntu) machines, but I need to get packets on the VPN 1 pc which is an Ubuntu server, so no Fiddler :)

Comment: I kind of assumed the PC was Linux due to it running OpenSwan and iptables but your right about fiddler.

Comment: Fair enough. In that case, install tcpdump on the VPN1 machine and use the -i option to have it sniff on the internal interface: that'll give you the cleartext of what's going on the VPN. You'll most likely need to craft a filter for the traffic you want to see but that's isn't too hard. If you have problem, ask a specific question about the filter and someone (me?) will answer: it's usually easy stuff.